# How to access links provided on one's timeline?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, feed

I would like to have access to the links one shared on their timeline.

Using the API Graph Explorer, I see there is a way to access "links". However, it returns empty data. I believe that this might have been used when posting links in FB was done in a special way, different than posting "usual" status.

Then, I thought, I should probably get all the stream and filter the data for links. But at that point, I'm a little confused:
There are THREE different actions that seem to provide the very same data: 
  - https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
  - .../me/posts
  - .../me/statuses

Are they actually all the same?

In addition, all seem to provide me information that is not up to date, but is true for some point in the near past. Moreover, I would like to know how I can get the relevant data from the beginning of the FB usage, or at least, for a given period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Do an HTTP Get to `me/links` to get the most recent links the user has shared.

To limit it to a timeframe, you can do `me/links?since=YYY&until=ZZZ`.

Or you can use the paging object to get the previous and next url to use to get that other page of data.

Comment: Thank you.
But the me/links returns an empty structure:
{
  "data": [
  ]
}

While there certainly are links, which I can see as regular "statuses"/"feed"/"posts"

Comment: The me links will return empty results if you don't use a valid token, or you user has no shared links.  I did me/links on my personal account with the appropriate permissions and I was able to see all the links I shared.  I think you need to double-check your access_token in the linter to make sure you have the correct permissions